# OSError: [Errno 19] Failed to open the uinput device: No such device

Tags: python, linux, raspbian, uinput

I am pretty new to raspberry and Linux. I am trying to run basic example of python library [uinput](http://tjjr.fi/sw/python-uinput/) on Raspbian (r Pi 3 B) with following code:

```
import uinput

device = uinput.Device([
        uinput.BTN_LEFT,
        uinput.BTN_RIGHT,
        uinput.REL_X,
        uinput.REL_Y,
        ])

for i in range(20):
    device.emit(uinput.REL_X, 5)
    device.emit(uinput.REL_Y, 5)
```

I get the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/pi/Desktop/t1.py", line 7, in 
    uinput.REL_Y,
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/uinput/**init**.py", line 178, in **init**
    self.**uinput_fd = fd or fdopen()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/uinput/__init**.py", line 84, in fdopen
    return _libsuinput.suinput_open()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/uinput/**init**.py", line 70, in _open_error_handler
    raise OSError(code, msg)

OSError: [Errno 19] Failed to open the uinput device: No such device
What is wrong? What do I need to change and where?

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: shouldn't you `open` the device? I mean `with Device as device`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is the `uinput` driver module loaded?

Try:

```
$ lsmod | grep uinput
```

Probably that will display nothing, which would mean that the driver is not loaded. Try loading it:

```
$ modprobe uinput
```

Then try your Python code. If you are not running your code with root privileges you will probably then get a `PermissionError` due to the access permissions on the `/dev/uinput` device file.

Comment: you were right, your first command printed nothing. the second command i had to run with sudo and python code then gave exactly the error you say.

Comment: then it starts to throw "ImportError: No module named 'uinput'".

Comment: if i run script without sudo and right after import i insert line print(uinput) it prints `<module 'uinput' from '/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/uinput/__init__.py'>` which i guess is correct

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment? I am not really that familiar with `uinput` so I could be wrong, but since it involves device drivers I would expect that it should be used only by privileged users.

Comment: well, i dont know how to answer at all. how do i know if i run a virtual environment?

Comment: If you don't know then you probably aren't using one, however, why can't your root user load the module? Install `python-uinput` in the global site packages.

Comment: so i added it using pip3 and managed to run that example code (had to `import time` library and add to loop line `time.sleep(0.5)` to see anything happen but that is already another story). Thanks a ton for the quick help!